# Tensorflow Object Detection

Tags: opencv, tensorflow

Hi while working with Tensorflow Object detection, while playing around with the Code supplied by Dat Tran GitHub

```
https://medium.com/towards-data-science/building-a-real-time-object-recognition-app-with-tensorflow-and-opencv-b7a2b4ebdc32
```

I am trying to work out how can i print out a message to the console based on the object that was classified / detected i tried

```
if classes == 'Louis':
        print('Hello Louis')
```

But doesn't seem to work, i did try doing the following

```
 for label in classes:
            if ('{Name}'.format(**label) == 'louis'):
                print('Hello Louis')
```

but i get the following Error

```
File "object_detection_app.py", line 61, in detect_objects
    if ('{Name}'.format(**label) == 'person'):
TypeError: format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not numpy.ndarray
```

It works if i do an else if statement with the output of hello. It would just it keeps printing no matter if an object is detected or not.

```
from utils import FPS, WebcamVideoStream
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pool
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017'
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, 'object_detection', MODEL_NAME, 'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, 'object_detection', 'data', 'myHousePets_label_map.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 90

# Loading label map
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES,
                                                            use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


def detect_objects(image_np, sess, detection_graph):
    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

    # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
    boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

    # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
    # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
    scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
    # Actual detection.
    (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
        [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict ={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

    # Visualization of the results of a detection.
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8)

    if classes == 'Louis':
        print('Hello Louis')
    return image_np


def worker(input_q, output_q):
    # Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.
    detection_graph = tf.Graph()
    with detection_graph.as_default():
        od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
            serialized_graph = fid.read()
            od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
            tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

        sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

    fps = FPS().start()
    while True:
        fps.update()
        frame = input_q.get()
        output_q.put(detect_objects(frame, sess, detection_graph))
    fps.stop()
    sess.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-src', '--source', dest='video_source', type=int,
                        default=0, help='Device index of the camera.')
    parser.add_argument('-wd', '--width', dest='width', type=int,
                        default=480, help='Width of the frames in the video stream.')
    parser.add_argument('-ht', '--height', dest='height', type=int,
                        default=360, help='Height of the frames in the video stream.')
    parser.add_argument('-num-w', '--num-workers', dest='num_workers', type=int,
                        default=2, help='Number of workers.')
    parser.add_argument('-q-size', '--queue-size', dest='queue_size', type=int,
                        default=5, help='Size of the queue.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    logger.setLevel(multiprocessing.SUBDEBUG)

    input_q = Queue(maxsize=args.queue_size)
    output_q = Queue(maxsize=args.queue_size)
    pool = Pool(args.num_workers, worker, (input_q, output_q))

    video_capture = WebcamVideoStream(src=args.video_source,
                                      width=args.width,
                                      height=args.height).start()
    fps = FPS().start()

    while True:  # fps._numFrames < 120
        frame = video_capture.read()
        input_q.put(frame)

        t = time.time()

        cv2.imshow('Video', output_q.get())
        fps.update()



        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    fps.stop()
    print('[INFO] elapsed time (total): {:.2f}'.format(fps.elapsed()))
    print('[INFO] approx. FPS: {:.2f}'.format(fps.fps()))
    pool.terminate()
    video_capture.stop()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, `classes` is a multi-dimensional array so you can't just compare it to the constant `Louis`.

I am not sure of its structure so here's my recommendation.

Add `print classes.shape` right before your visualization. This will console log the number of rows and columns of your array.
[This](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) and [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) will help you better understand it.

To further understand the printed results, I'd also recommend adding `print classes` right below the shape in order for you to see the actual contents of the array and further understand its shape.

After doing so, you can go ahead and iterate over it accordingly to search for `Louis`. [`.nditer()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html) is an efficient way of doing so. [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.sort.html) are a few more routines which may be of interest as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `visualization_utils.py` and use this: `print(display_str)` inside the function [`visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`](https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app/blob/3b99dec0f0a13e9c916bd75b0904f561b2a015da/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py#L323).

That will print the classes and scores per frame.

Answer (score 0):

go into the visualize_utils.py in the utils folder under the current model directory and start tweaking with it.

if you want to tweak with perse print something if you detect an object whose label is already known, you may want to do the following under

```
def visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(.....):
```

Say if you want to print the current object to python command line modify the following section of above mention method as follows

```
else:
    if not agnostic_mode:
      if classes[i] in category_index.keys():
        class_name = category_index[classes[i]]['name']
        if (class_name == 'person'):
          print(class_name + "Detected")
```

Please correct me / add upon to my answer ! Thanks and Welcome in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range (classes.size):
    if(classes[0][i] == CLASS_OF_LOUIS and scores[0][i]>0.5):
          print("Hello Louis")
```

**You must specify a treshold for detection of LOUIS. Maybe this code can work. CLASS_OF_LOUIS is an integer. It is the id number of louis in your labelmap.pbtxt file. Code should look like following.**

```
from utils import FPS, WebcamVideoStream
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pool
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017'
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, 'object_detection', MODEL_NAME, 'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, 'object_detection', 'data', 'myHousePets_label_map.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 90

# Loading label map
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES,
                                                            use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


def detect_objects(image_np, sess, detection_graph):
    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

    # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
    boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

    # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
    # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
    scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
    # Actual detection.
    (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
        [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict ={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

    # Visualization of the results of a detection.
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8)

    for i in range (classes.size):
        if(classes[0][i] == CLASS_OF_LOUIS and scores[0][i]>0.5):
              print("Hello Louis")
    return image_np


def worker(input_q, output_q):
    # Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.
    detection_graph = tf.Graph()
    with detection_graph.as_default():
        od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
            serialized_graph = fid.read()
            od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
            tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

        sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

    fps = FPS().start()
    while True:
        fps.update()
        frame = input_q.get()
        output_q.put(detect_objects(frame, sess, detection_graph))
    fps.stop()
    sess.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-src', '--source', dest='video_source', type=int,
                        default=0, help='Device index of the camera.')
    parser.add_argument('-wd', '--width', dest='width', type=int,
                        default=480, help='Width of the frames in the video stream.')
    parser.add_argument('-ht', '--height', dest='height', type=int,
                        default=360, help='Height of the frames in the video stream.')
    parser.add_argument('-num-w', '--num-workers', dest='num_workers', type=int,
                        default=2, help='Number of workers.')
    parser.add_argument('-q-size', '--queue-size', dest='queue_size', type=int,
                        default=5, help='Size of the queue.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    logger.setLevel(multiprocessing.SUBDEBUG)

    input_q = Queue(maxsize=args.queue_size)
    output_q = Queue(maxsize=args.queue_size)
    pool = Pool(args.num_workers, worker, (input_q, output_q))

    video_capture = WebcamVideoStream(src=args.video_source,
                                      width=args.width,
                                      height=args.height).start()
    fps = FPS().start()

    while True:  # fps._numFrames < 120
        frame = video_capture.read()
        input_q.put(frame)

        t = time.time()

        cv2.imshow('Video', output_q.get())
        fps.update()



        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    fps.stop()
    print('[INFO] elapsed time (total): {:.2f}'.format(fps.elapsed()))
    print('[INFO] approx. FPS: {:.2f}'.format(fps.fps()))
    pool.terminate()
    video_capture.stop()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```